# Descargar varios ficheros desde servidor ftp con php

Tags: php, ftp

de antemano he leido varias respuestas de este foro y tambien lei la referencia de ftp del manual de php pero no logro determinar cómo descargar todos los archivos que estén en un servidor ftp.

hice una pequeña prueba con este codigo que funciona sin problema.

```
$local_file = 'archivo1.php';  //fichero local
$server_file = 'archivo1.php';  //fichero remoto
$ftp_server="ftp.myserver.com";  //servidor ftp
$ftp_user_name="update@myserver.com.co";       //user ftp
$ftp_user_pass="Mypass123";    //pass ftp
 
$conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server); //creando la conexión
 
// login 
$login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass);
 
// descargando el fichero y guardandole en local
if (ftp_get($conn_id, $local_file, $server_file, FTP_BINARY)) {
    echo "Se descargo el archivo! $local_file\n";
}
else {
    echo "No se logro descargar \n";
}
// cierra la conexion
ftp_close($conn_id);
```

Como lo mencioné funciona bien, pero solo si intento guardar de a un (1) archivo archivo1.php, pero como puedo lograr que me descargue todo el contenido de una carpeta del servidor ftp sin tener que listar o mencionar los archivos 1 a 1, hay alguna manera de hacerlo? o necesariamente tengo que mencionar los archivos que deseo descargar?

Gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hola y gracias por contestar, pues ante este inconveniente se me ocurrió que puedo dejar en el servidor FTP un archivo .zip con todo el contenido que deseo descargar, luego vía ftp lo descargo y con php lo extraigo en donde necesite actualizar los archivos, era sencillo de hacer, si alguien necesita orientación con gusto lo ayudo.

Answer (score 0):

Hasta donde conozco, sí, usted debe indicar cada uno de los archivos a descargar. Esto está determinado por el funcionamiento del protocolo FTP.
Se puede auxiliar de otras [funciones FTP](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.ftp.php) para listar los archivos, y luego iterar sobre esa lista y descargarlos.

También le recomiendo que valore el uso de alguna biblioteca PHP que simplifique el uso de estas funciones FTP, por ejemplo:
[PHP FTP Client Library](https://github.com/altayalp/php-ftp-client)
[Lazzard/FtpClient](https://github.com/lazzard/php-ftp-client)
[nicolab/php-ftp-client](https://github.com/Nicolab/php-ftp-client)

Otra observación, compruebe cuantas descargas simultaneas permite su servidor FTP, quizás pueda hacer descargas simultáneas, si es el caso, investigue como paralelizar la solución (tal vez le sirva [parallel](https://github.com/amphp/parallel)).